# Minimum supported Gradle version error when installing Firebase

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make push notifications for my app. I started with a blank app (react-native init), then installed firebase, linked it, and followed the instructions. First, here https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup
then here https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/android
I added all the necessary lines in both build.gradle, and changed gradle url to gradle-4.4-all.zip
But when I try to run the app, there's an error

```
Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
```

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.10.1. Current version is 4.4. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/irondsd/dev/RNFirebase/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-4.10.1-all.zip

I tried to make it over again twice, to make sure I didn't miss anything. But I get same error every time. I tried to google, but couldn't find much.

This is what I added to project level build.gradle

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

in app/build.gradle:

```
implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"

// at the end of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the react native version and react-native-firebase version

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.4",
"react-native-firebase": "^5.3.0"
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and change distributionUrl into
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-all.zip` 

It will solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure? Because they ask you to change it for a reason. It was 4.10 and I changed it to 4.4 following firebase installation procedure.

Comment: Yes, because I am using it now. And changing into 4.10 solve the problem for me.

Comment: delete your  ```.gradle```  file then try again

Comment: I has to be gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
with 4.10 I was getting the same error, but 4.10.1 actually worked. Thank you.

Comment: I honestly didn't think of that, because it was too obvious to switch version back. I assumed it wouldn't work.